# angular $scope.$apply does not work properly with form.submit()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, scope, angularjs-scope

I have following code, which submit form after response is set to hidden field. The problem is, if I don't wait for few miliseconds or second, then it just don't save it, if i wait little bit and then submit form, then it works fine.

I basically want to submit form as soon as the value is set to paymentToken (hidden field).

```
braintree.setup($scope.serverToken, "dropin", {
            container: "dropin-container",
            onPaymentMethodReceived: function (response)
            {
                $scope.paymentToken = 'testing';

                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.paymentToken = response.nonce;
                    console.log($scope.paymentToken);
                    document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); // form is submitted, but no paymentToken is not set yet.
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your changes to the scope variable (i.e. `$scope.paymentToken = ...`) don't get applied to the UI (i.e. the form that you are submitting) till after the $scope.$apply completes.

You basically need to move your `submit()` into the next cycle. One easy way to do this is

```
    console.log($scope.paymentToken);
    $timeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }, 0);
});
```

after injecting $timeout ofcourse.